# QGIS losing CRS on saving (Make Permanent and Export)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am completely untrained and new to GIS.

I am creating buffers around polygon vectors in QGIS. I have overcome a lot of problems with this, mostly pertaining to getting the buffer tool to allow meters/feet in the distance (versus degrees), and usually resolved by paying attention to the CRS. The problem I've hit now is when I save things to make them permanently part of the project, the CRS is changing, despite me hard-setting it.

Example:

1. Make a new project, add base map (OpenStreetMap)
2. Confirm CRS follows the new base map ("WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator")
3. Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer
4. Choose a KML file with a polygon
5. Zoom to layer to ensure it looks right, it does...
6. Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer
7. Distance is stuck in "degrees".
8. Check layer CRS, it's "EPSG:4326 - WGS 84". I know at this point I need to reproject this layer with a new CRS
9. Vector > Data Management > Reproject Layer
10. Choose "Project CRS ... WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator"
11. Check the new "Reprojected layer" and confirm it does have the new CRS
12. Buffer tool now shows meters, so I create a 10 meter buffer just for testing - It works as expected AND the buffered layer also has the correct CRS
13. SAVE the temporary layers by alt-clicking, Make Permanent
    (NOTE: I am saving as KML)
14. Now that the layer is no longer temporary, I go to create another buffer based on it, and it's now stuck in "degrees" unit for distance
15. I check the layer properties, it has reverted back to the troublesome "EPSG:4326 - WGS 84", which I presume is the cause for this change
    (NOTE: Rather than Make Permanent, I have also tried Export > Save Features As, which opens "Save Vector Layer as..." window, which allows me to save as KML AND specify the CRS. The CRS is correct in this pane. But when I open the KML, it reverts back to the unwanted CRS)

My expectation is that when I save a layer (Make Permanent), it will retain the current CRS. At the very least, when I export it, where it actually let's me specify the CRS, I feel the CRS should remain the same. I don't understand why it is changing.

How can I get the CRS to persist with the save?

I'm wondering if I'm going about this completely wrong, with the reprojection or anything else.

Comment: KML files do only support EPSG:4326, its indeed weird though that its saving without a warning. If you want another CRS, I suggest to use another file format. Another hint: pseudo mercator is not a good choice to do accurate measurings. If you need exact buffers, better use a local metric CRS like UTM.

Comment: I just discovered that, if I save as a SHP file, the CRS remains. Is the entire problem that KML files only allow "EPSG:4326 - WGS 84" CRS? Really sorry if this was the entire issue. I think I can work around them being SHP files. I work between QGIS and Google Earth (which seems to prefer KML). I can make this work if this is all there is. I'm not sure if leaving this question here might be beneficial to someone in the future, so for now I will leave it. I am also interested on any advice for the process I am performing.

Comment: I see @MrXsquared answered with this solution as well. Thank you so much! This was really confusing me. I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.